# Importing the text from a tab delimited text file into an existing Excel template C#

Tags: c#, excel, import

I work in configuration management and once a week I am required to build a delta MRI (records index) of objects in the main engineering design tool we use.  Currently The tool will run nightly on a Sunday and place the text files into a directory, then we manually copy and paste the data into a formatted blank spreadsheet.  The total number of files output is 6 and there is 7 tabs.  The seventh tab is the dedicated "cover" page.  The file names match the names of the tabs so file USER_INDEX.txt will go into the USER_INDEX tab and so on.  The headers on the spreadsheet are at line 6 and will be the top line copied over.

Honestly I am not sure where to start here.  What I would like is to click a button in C#, import the text, the click another button to select the MRI spreadsheet and paste it into the specific tab in the specific position.  I want to do any formatting (comma removal etc. manually using VBA).

I apologise for the long winded post, I see lots of info about importing text using Excel, or converting a text file to an Excel document, but nothing around importing to a specific tab and starting at a specific row (6).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Couldn’t you open the Excel file and import the text? Excel can read tab delimited files.

Comment: Yeah the option is there, but it won't import into the pre-existing format.  It creates new columns upon import.  I am just trying to make this as brain dead as possible because if I get hit by a bus the next guy should just be able to click a couple of buttons if you know what I mean.

Comment: Are you sure about this... _"but it won't import into the pre-existing format."_ ...?

Comment: Yeah I try to import to column A row 6 (pasting the data to the right) it creates a bunch of new columns before column A, basically pushing everything to the right.  I am very much a novice with this though so chances are I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Well… If you want to open an Excel file and manually add the data cell by cell using C# code, then you will need to decide “which” Excel library you want to use. This may depend on your environment. So, you may want to ask what library is allowed. If you plan to run this as a stand alone on your own machine… then pick your own poison. I have found EPPLus to be a good choice for non-commercial use. However, there are others… some are free others not so free. And Interop is always a last resort.